# Hard resetting link after SSD firmware upgrade

Tags: hardware, kernel, ssd

**System**: HP Omen 15-5003nl

**SSD:** SanDisk SD6PP4M-256GB-1006

**SSD Firmware:** A200906

**Kernel:** 3.19.0-58-generic

I recently upgraded my SSD firmware and it fixed a serious ahcpi freeze bug on Windows partition (http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Boot-and-Lockup/HP-Omen-system-hangs/td-p/4990788).
Sometimes the system freezed some seconds with Linux OS too, so I hoped to resolve all problems with this new firmware.

On the contrary, now my dmesg is full of:

```
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113563] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x20000000 SErr 0x50000 action 0xe frozen
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113567] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113569] ata5: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake }
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113572] ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113575] ata5.00: cmd 61/48:e8:00:3e:7e/01:00:16:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq 167936 out
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113575] res 40/00:e4:00:f7:32/00:00:19:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113577] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
5/4/2016 00:40:26 Dago kernel [ 322.113580] ata5: hard resetting link
5/4/2016 00:40:27 Dago kernel [ 322.838234] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
5/4/2016 00:40:27 Dago kernel [ 322.839183] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
5/4/2016 00:40:27 Dago kernel [ 322.839247] ata5: EH complete
```

209 errors in 20minutes.

I did a system ssd check and no errors are found.
This is my smartctl log:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-4.1.0-040100-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SanDisk SD6PP4M-256G-1006
Serial Number:    144042400840
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 c952d9848
Firmware Version: A200906
User Capacity:    256.060.514.304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Apr  5 00:45:00 2016 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  21) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2351
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       535
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   099   099   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       154626949121
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       47
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   253   253   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   070   002   ---    Old_age   Always       -       870
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   051   025   014    Old_age   Always       -       49
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       517979766784

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2348         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2330         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2311         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2260         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2231         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2204         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2163         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2105         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2023         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1995         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1976         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1905         -
#13  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%      1894         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1893         -
#15  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1893         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1892         -
#17  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1892         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1891         -
#19  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1891         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1890         -
#21  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1889         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I tried several kernels (4.0.5, 4.0.9, 4.1.0, 4.5) without success.
Should I report this bug somewhere else? Where? Have you some suggestions?

**Update 1**: Dmesg errors show only with AC power plug plugged in.

Comment: Is Windows working

Comment: Yes, it's working without any errors now on Windows

Comment: Try upgrading to kernel 4.4

Comment: No improvements with 4.4.6-040406-generic #201603161231 kernel

Comment: Can you boot you system

Comment: What do you mean? If I can boot my system?
Of course! I'm using Elementary 0.3.2 Freya 64bit at this moment

Comment: How does this annoy you?

Comment: It does, I can't say which side effects this problem have. I/O SSD speed? The system log full of errors is not a good signal

Comment: Is your SSD any slower. Maybe the update removed some Linux features

Comment: Removed? It's a bug :|
Dmesg errors show only with AC power plug plugged in.